# Is there any solution to match the Kendo date picker value and grid date column value

Tags: kendo-ui

I have a requirement that need to select to and from date ,so that the date should match in grid and display the result.But the grid column with date contains date+time .So my question is it possible to ignore time and read only date in to and from date pickers and match the value in grid.

```
$("#datepicker").kendoDatePicker({
      dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy", 
format    : "dd-MM-yy "});


$("#datepicker1").kendoDatePicker({
  dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy", 
format    : "dd-MM-yy "});


 var result=$("#grid").kendoGrid({
    filterable: true,


  columns: [
    { field: "FirstName", title: "First Name" },
    { field: "LastName", title: "Last Name" },
       { field: "dob", title: "DOB" ,  format: "{0:dd-MM-yy HH:mm:ss}"}
  ],
  dataSource: {
    data: [
        { FirstName: "Joe", LastName: "Smith" ,dob:"2013-02-18 19:54:13"},
        { FirstName: "Jane", LastName: "Smith" ,dob:"2013-02-18 20:55:14" },
        { FirstName: "Jane", LastName: "Smith" ,dob:"2013-05-30 21:56:15" },
        { FirstName: "Jane", LastName: "Smith" ,dob:"2013-05-18 22:57:16" },
        { FirstName: "Jane", LastName: "Smith" ,dob:"2013-02-19 20:55:20" },
        { FirstName: "Jane", LastName: "Smith" ,dob:"2013-02-24 20:56:14" },
        { FirstName: "Jane", LastName: "Smith" ,dob:"2013-03-26 20:57:14" },
        { FirstName: "Jane", LastName: "Smith" ,dob:"2013-02-28 20:42:14" },
        { FirstName: "Jane", LastName: "Smith" ,dob:"2013-03-22 11:55:14" },
        { FirstName: "Jane", LastName: "Smith" ,dob:"2013-03-27 20:55:14" },
        { FirstName: "Jane", LastName: "Smith" ,dob:"2013-04-18 20:55:14" },
        { FirstName: "Jane", LastName: "Smith" ,dob:"2013-04-23 20:55:14" },
        { FirstName: "Jane", LastName: "Smith" ,dob:"2013-04-24 20:55:14" }
    ],
     schema: {


     data: function (data) {
            $.each(data, function (i, val) {
                val.dob = kendo.parseDate(val.dob, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
            });
            return data;
        }
        }   

  }
}).data("kendoGrid");


$("#datepicker, #datepicker1").on("change", function (){
    var mindate = $('#datepicker').data("kendoDatePicker").value();
    var maxdate = $('#datepicker1').data("kendoDatePicker").value();
    var condition = {
        logic  : "and",
        filters: [
        ]
    };
  if (mindate !== null) {
    condition.filters.push({ field: "dob", operator: "ge", value: mindate });
  }
  if (maxdate !== null) {
    condition.filters.push({ field: "dob", operator: "le", value: maxdate });
  }
    result.dataSource.filter(condition);
});
```

Here is the fiddle I updated  [Kendo grid filter with to and from dates](http://jsfiddle.net/5bchz/40/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define an additional columns that has the date without time and use this column for filtering.

This can be done in your `data` function:

```
data: function (data) {
    $.each(data, function (i, val) {
        val.dob2 = kendo.parseDate(val.dob, "yyyy-MM-dd");
        val.dob = kendo.parseDate(val.dob, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    });
    return data;
}
```

And the filtering part:

```
$("#datepicker, #datepicker1").on("change", function (){
    var mindate = $('#datepicker').data("kendoDatePicker").value();
    var maxdate = $('#datepicker1').data("kendoDatePicker").value();
    var condition = {
        logic  : "and",
        filters: [
        ]
    };
    if (mindate !== null) {
        condition.filters.push({ field: "dob2", operator: "ge", value: mindate });
    }
    if (maxdate !== null) {
        condition.filters.push({ field: "dob2", operator: "le", value: maxdate });
    }
    result.dataSource.filter(condition);
});
```

A second option is defining the filtering conditions as:

```
if (mindate !== null) {
    condition.filters.push({ field: "dob", operator: "ge", value: new Date(mindate) });
}
if (maxdate !== null) {
    condition.filters.push({ field: "dob", operator: "le", value: new Date(maxdate) });
}
```

Where we add a `new Date(...)` for *adding* time to the date.

**NOTE:** This is valid as far as you are doing client side filtering. If you are doing server side filtering the query in the server should be easily changed to deal with this.

Comment: Means before getting the data it should be parsed.

Comment: The second solutions does not require you to change the parse function, just need to change the event handler for `change` event. See it here: http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/TXUDw/

Comment: thanks OnaBai,but the problem i am getting is if I enter To:18-02-13 and from:18-02-13 same the value is not getting filtered and if I enter 30-05-13, before entering second date it is getting filtered.

Comment: is there any alternative OnaBai,and if I enter From date as 30-05-13 21:56:15 it is getting filtered ,it is not considering to date.

Comment: From that I got one point from date should be less than to date and If I enter 18-02-13 and 30-05-13 the dates in between them are getting filtered

Comment: Sorry, I've just realized that I was wrong and were mixing your problem with the other that I refer to -that's why I deleted my last comments-. Would you mind checking this http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/5bchz/86/ (1st proposed solution) and explain me again what is failing?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean, maybe I see a different result because of the different timezone. Which value(s) is(are) not being displayed?

Comment: Sure..!With the hard code data it is working fine ,but When I am using the service data the scenario is not working.

Comment: That makes sense since solution 1 only works with local data. For server side data either you change the server for shifting `to` date to the end of the day or you do in the client based on proposed solution 2.

Comment: Check this http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/5bchz/87/ and try (even in local) setting the same day for `from` and `to` and then comment the line that moves to the end of the day `maxdate.setHours(23,59,59,999);` You should see the difference.